# Creating view for update table via foregien key access in django

Tags: postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am really new to django and stuck in using foreign key in django queries.Can anyone help me.

Situation:I created a sign up page with username and email field.So when a new user registered, its username and email address saved to auth_user table.

Q: I want to create a model instance in class UserDetails each time a new user register. or you can say entry of user as a foregien key in table userdetails. I am using postgresql database.

Myapp/models.py

```
   class Pincode(models.Model):
        pincode = models.CharField("PinCode",null=False)
        geom = GeopositionField("Location")
        objects = models.GeoManager()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' %(self.pincode)

   class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='User_Details',unique=True)
    pin= models.ForeignKey(Pincode,related_name='pin', null= True, blank=True)
    rating= models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s, %s' % (self.user,  self.pin, self.rating)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    update_user_details()

    return render_to_response("larb/index.html",
                              RequestContext(request))


def update_user_details(request): ## **Stuck here**
    user_details = UserDetails.objects.all()
    new_entry= User.objects.exclude()  # Don't know how to do
```

currently i am thinking of creating a function in the views that update the table. 
first it checks for new entries means entries in auth_user which are not in userdetails table. If found update userdetails table.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i solved it and it's seems fine now:

Here is views.py code

```
def index(request):
    update_user_details()
    return render_to_response("larb/index.html",
                              RequestContext(request))


def update_user_details():
   id_past_entries = UserDetails.objects.all().values_list('user_id', flat = True)
   new_entries = User.objects.exclude(id__in=id_past_entries)
   if new_entries:
       for new_id in new_entries:
            new = User.objects.get(id=new_id)
            UserDetails.objects.create(user=new)
            UserDetails.save()
```